# Prove that the eigenspace is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $A$ be an $n$ by $n$ square matrix. Define the eigenspace of an
>    eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ to be the kernel of $A-\lambda_iI$. Prove that
>    the eigenspace of any matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ is a
>    vector space.

Is my proof correct?

We know that $\ker(A-\lambda_i I) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : (A-\lambda_i I)x = 0\}$. Let $B = A-\lambda_i I$, then we need to show that the kernel of $B$ is a vector space. However, note that $\ker(B) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, so instead of verifying the axioms of a vector space, we can simply show that $\ker(B)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. First note that $\ker(B)$ is non-empty since it contains the trivial solution $x=0$. To show that $\ker(B)$ is closed under addition, let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be vectors in $\ker(B)$. Thus, we have $Bx_1 = 0$ and $Bx_2 = 0$ and so we have $B(x_1+x_2) = Bx_1 + Bx_2 = 0 + 0 = 0$, so $x_1+x_2 \in \ker(B)$. To show that $\ker(B)$ is closed under scalar multiplication, let $k$ be any scalar and $x_1 \in \ker(B)$. Then, $B(kx_1) = kBx_1 = k0 = 0$, so $kx_1 \in \ker(B)$. Since $\ker(B)$ is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence must be a vector space itself.

Comment: Yes, it looks perfectly good to me.

Comment: One small, tiny remark (which doesn't invalidate anything but is just about taste). As you have probably noticed, the kernel of any matrix (or linear map) is a subspace of the domain of said matrix(/linear map). It might be a tiny bit more neat to prove this more general thing as a seperate theorem (for every $B$ ...) and then just use that theorem.